# How to use string indexes in c++ arrays (like php)?

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I use a string index in a c++ array (like in php)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use [`std::map`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) to get an associative container in which you can lookup values by a string index. A map like `std::map<std::string, int>` would associate integer values with `std::string` lookup keys.

Answer (score 4):

They're called associative arrays (or dictionaries) and the allow you to use any type you want as a key, instead of just integers. They're natively supported in PHP, in C++ you should probably use [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) unless you're in .net, [which has its own dictionary class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing is probably a std::map.

Check out the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(C%2B%2B)) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Many have said that `std::map` is a choice. To be as effective as array index using, I think `std::unordered_map` may be better.

Because performance of `std::map` with `key_type` is a string possibly be very bad. Since comparing two strings will take `O(string::size())` time in the worst case. So if the index strings are very long and similar and the number of them is too big, I would say that using `std::map` is unrealistic.

And I have some better way to implement it, but I'm not sure if they are feasible(especially the second one).

1. Use a Trie.
2. Use `string_view` instead of string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) to have an object with behavior similar to associative array.

Answer (score 1):

There is a data structure called [Matrix library](https://github.com/pwwiur/Matrix). This library supports 2D arrays and associative arrays that you are looking for.

```
Matrix<string> arr(3, 2);

// setting keys
arr[0][0] = "name";
arr[0][1] = "lastname";

// using array
arr[1]["name"] = "John";
arr[1]["lastname"] = "Parkers";

arr[2]["name"] = "Sam";
arr[2]["lastname"] = "Bendrou";
```

Here you can find [documentation](https://www.amirforsati.ir/doc/11) of Matrix library.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality called Map in general.
If you already use Boost you can use their Maps, if not you must think twice :) Ok, if not Dimtry right - std::map is what you need.